# Delete s from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query as following (not the actual one):

```
DELETE s
FROM
table_expiration s INNER JOIN table_existance d 
ON s.ssn = d.ssn AND
s.latest_date = d.latest_date
```

I don't have any data in those tables so I cannot actually test the query. Can someone explain to me what's the purpose of `Delete s`? (I always thought the `Delete` statement should just be `Delete from table`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete s` tells the query to delete the rows from `table_expiration` which has the alias `s`. Replacing `s` with `d` would delete rows from `table_existance`.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3b57/3)

It may be worth pointing out here that you cannot delete from both tables involved in the join directly by doing `delete s,d` in SQL Server (MySQL lets you do that I think).